# How to get JSON returned from POSTing text/turtle to Blazegraph?

Tags: json, xml, blazegraph

My update is working because I can query the data I'd sent, but the response I get is in XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><data modified="429" milliseconds="437"/>
```

I am setting the request header Accept:

```
con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/sparql-results+json,application/json");
```

Comment: `con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");` doesnt work?

Comment: no, it just returns an xml string with the results. I tested removing the application/sparql-results+json so it only had application/json and still get the xml string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this **parameter** (not header) instead:
`format=json`